# How to hoist XML namespaces to root element

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xml-namespaces, workflow-foundation

If I have an XML file with namespaces like:

```xml
<root>

<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.namespaces.com/namespaceOne">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<h:table xmlns:h="https://www.namespaces.com/namespaceTwo">
  <h:name>African Coffee Table</h:name>
  <h:width>80</h:width>
  <h:length>120</h:length>
</h:table>

</root>
```

I want to hoist all of the namespaces to the root element, like this:

```xml
<root xmlns:h="http://www.namespaces.com/namespaceOne" xmlns:h1="https://www.namespaces.com/namespaceTwo">

<h:table>
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<h1:table>
  <h1:name>African Coffee Table</h1:name>
  <h1:width>80</h1:width>
  <h1:length>120</h1:length>
</h1:table>

</root>
```

Is there a way to do this? Ideally automatically resolving conflicting namespace prefixes, as in the example above. I haven't committed to using *Linq to XML* or *System.Xml* yet, so either would be a possibility.

**There is one major constraint:** because of the environment I am working in, I can't write classes. I can write functions, but no new class definitions.

Comment: These XML documents are equivalent. Why move the namespace to the root?

Comment: Because the platform I am writing for expects it in that format.

Comment: Oh dear, another platform that can't deal with XML. Good luck. Have you considered reporting it as a bug of the platform?

Comment: I'm assuming those `f` elements were supposed to be `h`? Otherwise this isn't valid XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is pretty straightforward:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var namespaceAttributes = doc.Descendants()
    .SelectMany(x => x.Attributes())
    .Where(x => x.IsNamespaceDeclaration);
int count = 1;
foreach (var namespaceAttribute in namespaceAttributes)
{
    doc.Root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + $"h{count}", namespaceAttribute.Value));
    namespaceAttribute.Remove();
    count++;
}
```

We loop through all namespace declarations (`xmlns:foo="foo"`). For each one we find, we put a namespace attribute with the same URL on the root element, and remove that one.

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7P9f8C).

Note that this does slightly odd things if you have multiple namespaces with the same URL (e.g. if you have two lots of `xmlns:h="https://www.namespaces.com/namespaceOne"` on different children): it puts multiple `xmlns` declarations on the root element with the same URL, but all elements use the last such namespace. If you want to avoid that, just keep a list of namespaces you've added to the root element.

Comment: Thanks. Most important info is x.IsNamespaceDeclaration, and a refreshed appreciation for the power of linq to xml. 

However, will also need to update the node prefixes, so they reference the right namespace. Could be done by getting the parent and maintaining a list of namespaces.

Comment: @BenMann Have you tried it? You don't need to update the individual elements at all. When the document is parsed, each element's name is associated with the *URL* of the namespace, not the namespace's name. When you come to serialize the XDocument again, it notices that there's already an xmlns with the right URL for the name of each element, and substitutes in the xmlns's name. I added a link to a working demo.